# Can magic items be fixed using spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

My DM has house rules saying that armor takes damage in combat and that armor is destroyed after being dealt sufficient damage. Because it's expensive to replace magic armor all the time, I wanted to just use magic to fix my battered armor. The DM says a magic item can't be fixed by using the spell [*mending*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mending.htm). I disagree and think that's one of the purposes of spells like *mending* and [*make whole*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/makeWhole.htm). Who's correct?

Answer (score 12):

### Yes, but only if the item hasn't been completely destroyed

*Mending*, and *Make Whole* per the spell descriptions:

> The spell can repair a magic item, but the item’s magical abilities are not restored.

This means that a magic item can be repaired by the spells, so long as it has it intact enough to still hold magic and continue to function. The rules for [Magic Items](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#) corroborate this.

> #### Damaging Magic Items
>
> Magic items, unless otherwise noted, take damage as nonmagical items of the same sort. A damaged magic item continues to function, but if it is destroyed, all its magical power is lost.

And

> #### Repairing Magic Items
>
> Some magic items take damage over the course of an adventure. It costs no more to repair a magic item with the Craft skill than it does to repair its nonmagical counterpart. The make whole spell also repairs a damaged—*but not completely broken*—magic item.

Once a magic item has been *destroyed,* (or broken), it can only be repaired by someone with the appropriate feats and spells to create it, as per [Craft Magic Arms and Armor](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#craftMagicArmsAndArmor).

> #### Craft Magic Arms And Armor [Item Creation]
>
> You can also mend a **broken** magic weapon, suit of armor, or shield if it is one that you could make. Doing so costs half the XP, half the raw materials, and half the time it would take to craft that item in the first place.

Comment: I don't think a DM could really argue that broken in that context is equivalent to destroyed. That sentence is meaningless if they're not treated as equivalent (you can repair non-destroyed magic items for free). @HeyICanChan

Comment: @Eikre I took a very rules-oriented approach in this answer, because I felt that that best answered the general question ("Can Mending do that?") There is definitely room for a different answer to discuss the table- and social-dynamics implied in the question, if you want to write it. ;)

Comment: Nah, I don't have anything to say which isn't an appendix to the answer you've already given. I concur with what you've said completely and have only my comment to add over top of it.